# Play / Stop button javascript help needed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have an audio player in a PhoneGap App.

Taken a while (as I dont know JS) but ive managed to get the audio tracks playing and stopping.

In css when you hit the 'play' button it swaps to 'stop' button and hitting it stops the audio - so far so good.

Play and Stop works fine with one track - but I have 4 tracks on the page. If one track is playing and you press play on one of the other tracks the audio stops (correct) BUT does not play the new track??

Id like to be able to press play on the other tracks which stops the current track and plays the new one.

Heres the Js i have that runs it - hope i explained ok?

Thanks!

```
<script>
var audioPlaying = false;
var media;
function playAudio(src,trackname) {
    if (audioPlaying === true) {
        media.stop();
     }
     if (audioPlaying === false) {
         media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
         media.play();
         document.getElementById(trackname).className="playing";
         audioPlaying = true;
     }
}

// remove .playing when track is done 
function success() {
    $(".playing").removeClass("playing");
    audioPlaying = false;
}

//alert('great error');
function error_error(e) {
}

// stop playing
function stopAudio() {
    if (media) {
        media.stop();
        audioPlaying = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling `playAudio`? It would probably also be useful to see how you hook up the `playAudio` and `stopAudio` functions to the user interface elements.

Comment: This is the anchor:
<a onclick="playAudio('http://a1340.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music/5f/f9/95/mzi.yaopatvv.aac.p.m4a','t1')" class="" id="t1">

Comment: I did have a stop button in there at one point but its not very intuative to play and track then have to stop before paying another - a bit like on itunes previews - you can click tracks to hear them without having to hit a stop button!

Comment: Then how about simply calling `stopAudio` in the `onclick` handler, before calling `playAudio...`? It'll probably be a lot clearer once you set a breakpoint in `playAudio` and step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: I see what you mean but imagine the audio that is already playing, the play button changes to a stop icon (with css) and clicking the that would stop the audio and start the track again.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to stop, you can just set the new audio src and the player will play it.

Comment: That would be great but not sure how to code it ;-)

Comment: var playme = document.getElementById('playme'); playme.src='snd/SOUND.WAV'; playme.load();